# date is not coming in same format python csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, csv

I am trying to convert string to date and then adding in csv file , but what I am getting is date is in diff format in few columns and diff for others for example :

[image: as shown in image]

```
def update_date_format(date_time):
    try:
        date_formating = datetime.strptime(date_time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
    except:
        date_formating = datetime.strptime(date_time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

    final_date = date_formating.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p')
    return final_date
```

and I am using try : except because date is coming some times without milliseconds:

with milliseconds getting like this  `2022-02-17 08:29:36.345374` 
without  milliseconds getting like this  `2022-02-17 08:29:36`

**EDIT**  this issue is facing when opening csv with Excel .

Comment: could you show us an example of the input data?

Comment: Is that what you see in a text editor or what you get when you open it with Excel?

Comment: the example that is with `-` as separator doesn't contain seconds, but you are parsing it with seconds. So the parsing will fail.

Comment: @MarkRansom in Exel this issue is appearing , in linux csv opener it's fine. don't know it's weird

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki I posted already 2 type of strings I am getting as Input from database then converting it to datetime using above funtion and then writing on csv

Comment: Excel uses its own logic to determine what is a date and what isn't. It appears that some of your values aren't being read as dates but as strings instead.

Comment: you have to provide an example of the input that is not parsed correctly and what result do you get.

Comment: Wait, Excel? you don't mention Excel anywhere in your question, it's not even in the tag. so the question is about the raw string you get after the parsing I guess.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki I am creating a csv , and when opening with excel facing this , sorry let me add excel tag

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) You need to provide a runnable [mre].

Comment: consider reading the csv to a pandas dataframe ([docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)). then you could use [pandas.to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) to parse to datetime conveniently.